# AEM Dispatcher (4.3.3) always returning 200 instead of 304 (Apache 2.4.6)

Tags: apache, caching, aem, etag, http-caching

I have configured ETags (using ACS Commons ETag support) on my AEM server and disabled ETag on Apache. But once the file gets cached on the Dispatcher, Apache always returns 200 with response body instead of 304 Not modified. I have validated that the ETag value stored in the ".h" file and in the response is the same as the value of the "If-None-Match" header of the request.
If I remove the cached files from the dispatcher and resend the request then AEM correctly returns 304.

I have also disabled mod_deflate as I have found at some places that the deflate's "-gzip" suffix could cause issues with ETag matching.

Also, instead of ETag, I have tried a similar thing with Last-Modified and If-Modified-Since headers. But no luck with that as well. I have noticed that we generally have Last-Modified headers in place in most cases and I have never seen 304. So, it seems like it is not a version-specific issue. I couldn't find any configuration documentation related to this. Could someone please guide me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check this https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45023

I have enabled deflate

```
RequestHeader edit "If-None-Match" "^\"(.*)-gzip\"$" "\"$1\""

Header edit "ETag" "^\"(.*[^g][^z][^i][^p])\"$" "\"$1-gzip\""
```

Comment: As I said, I have disabled mod_deflate completely. So, this should not be related. Also, in one of the Apache's bug list I have found that there is some issue with ETag as well. So, I tried using Last-Modified. But no luck with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use Etags since it is diffcult to sync them across a cluster and Last Modified works fine.

```
# turn off Etags completely, since they will differ across the cluster
FileETag None

# FileETag None is not enough for every server.
Header unset ETag

# instead we use Expires and Cache-Control headers
ExpiresActive On

# set Expires default to 15 minutes, so browser caches for a visit
ExpiresDefault  "access plus 15 minutes"
# but a maybe few types are exempt from this
ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest   "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/xml  "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/xml   "access plus 0 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/json  "access plus 0 seconds"
# set CacheControl public header
# so content is cached in Firefox, even over https
# "public" keyword MUST be the first value in the header, or it will not work in FF
Header onsuccess edit Cache-Control "^(.*)$" "public, $1"
```

You can adjust the timeouts accordingly, depending on your content.

Comment: Somehow the Last-Modified property is not synced on our cluster. Different publishers have different jcr:lastModified value for the same node due to which we are not able to utilize it.

Comment: Did you check the instruction in https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-dispatcher/using/configuring/dispatcher-configuration.html?lang=en#caching-http-response-headers ? Maybe share that part of your config?

Comment: Yes. I checked that, Last-Modified header is getting cached in the headers file on the dispatcher and I made sure that the value is coming from AEM.
Below is the config which I am using currently:
                /headers {
   "Cache-Control"
   "Content-Disposition"
   "Content-Type"
   "Expires"
   "Last-Modified"
   "X-Content-Type-Options"
  }